# How can I write a decltype expression using a function that expects a non-const reference?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype

Consider:

```
int convert_it(std::string& x)
{
    return 5;
}

void takes_int_ref(int& i)
{
}
```

I want to write a function which only exists if `convert_it` can be applied and the result passed into `takes_int_ref`. That is, the function body is:

```
template <typename A>
void doit(A& a) 
{
    int i = convert_it(a);
    takes_int_ref(i);
}
```

However, if I do:

```
template <typename A>
auto doit(A& a) -> decltype(takes_int_ref(convert_it(a)), void())
```

it doesn't work because `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'`.

I thought of the following solution, which works:

```
template <typename T>
T& gimme_ref(T t) { throw std::runtime_error("No"); return t; }

template <typename A>
auto doit(A& a) -> decltype(takes_int_ref(gimme_ref(convert_it(a))), void())
```

However, it seems hackish and the `decltype` no longer reflects what the function body does. In essence the problem seems to be that `decltype` only takes an expression, while two statements are required in the function body here.

What would be the right approach to take here?

Comment: are `std::result_of` and `std::enable_if` any helpfull?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval):

```
template <typename A>
auto doit(A& a) -> decltype(
    takes_int_ref(std::declval<
       decltype(convert_it(std::declval<A&>()))
       &>()), void())
{ .. }
```

`std::declval<A&>()` gives you an expresion of type `A&`. `convert_it(A&)` will either be valid or not - if it's invalid, you fail there. If it's valid, say it has type `T`. Then, you try to call `takes_int_ref` with a `T&`, so to see if *that*'s valid. If it is, you'll get to the `void`. If it's not, substitution failure.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need! Question, why do you need the `&`s in the declval expressions?

Comment: @Claudiu Because you want an lvalue reference. `declval<T>()` gives you a `T&&`, but `declval<T&>()` gives you a `T&`.

Comment: Interestingly, this makes me think my version wasn't so hackish, if I just rename `gimme_ref` to `ref_of` and don't define the body at all, this looks cleaner: `decltype(takes_int_ref(ref_of(convert_it(a))), void())`

Comment: @Claudiu Yeah. I guess also `std::declval<A&>()` wasn't necessary, since `a` is already an `A&`. I guess I just put it there for gratuitousness. Yeah, let's go with that.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, after seeing the `std::declval` solution, my perception of what is hackish changed, and I ended up going with this:

```
template <typename T> T& lref_of(T&&);

template <typename A>
auto doit(A& a) -> decltype(takes_int_ref(lref_of(convert_it(a))), void()) 
{ .. }
```

Since I'm starting from an expression and not a type, it's cleaner to do `lref_of(convert_it(a))` than `std::declval<decltype(convert_it(a))&>()`. Plus, not defining `lref_of` gives a compile-time error if it's used in any code which is better than defining it to simply throw an exception at runtime.